# Customized field constructor with constraints

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have written my own field constructor like the following:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@*****************************************************
* Generate input according to Twitter Bootsrap rules *
******************************************************@
<div class="control-group @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label class="control-label" for="@elements.id">@elements.label @if(elements.field.constraints.map(c => c._1).contains("constraint.required")) {*}</label>
    <div class="controls">
        @elements.input
        <span class="help-inline">@elements.errors(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help-block">@elements.infos(elements.lang).mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to add a star symbol `*` after the label of the required elements.

It works fine with fields that have the `nonEmptyText` mapping in the form definition but my main concern is to do the same with the required email fields: may the field be defined as `email` or `optional(email)` in the form, the same constraint `constraint.email` is used.

So how can I find the difference in my field constructor and add the star only to the required email fields?

Comment: In Java you can define multiple constraints for a field. A required email field would have both the "Required" and "Email" constraints in the model, and an optional email field would only have the "Email" constraint. I have basically the same code in one of my custom field constructors and it works as expected. I don't know how to define multiple constraints in Scala though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Specifically for email:**

You can define your email address in the Form mapping like so:

```
import play.api.data.Forms.email
import play.api.data.validation.Constraints.nonEmpty

"email" -> email.verifying(nonEmpty)
```

This will add the constraint you expect: "constraint.required"